# Django : 'collections.OrderedDict' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a post request to module User which inherits AbstractUser using serializer UserSerializer, but I'm getting the error 'collections.OrderedDict' object is not callable on-field "PhoneNumber".
Serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= User
        fields="__all__"
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        user = User(
            username = self.validated_data.get('username'),
            first_name =self.validated_data.get('first_name'),
            last_name = self.validated_data.get('last_name'),
             email=self.validated_data.get('email'),
            Address=self.validated_data.get('Address'),
            PhoneNumber=self.validated_data('PhoneNumber'))
        user.save()
```

User Model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    Address=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    PhoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True,verbose_name='PhoneNumber')
    cdNumber = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True,verbose_name='cdNumber')
    cdDate=models.DateField(blank=True,null=True,verbose_name='cdDate')
    cdName = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True,verbose_name='cdName')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name+" "+self.last_name
```

Comment: I'd guess that `self.validated_data('PhoneNumber')` is supposed to be `self.validated_data.get('PhoneNumber')`, since that's how you're doing all the other values. You've missed the `get` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= User
        fields="__all__"
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        user = User(
            username = self.validated_data.get('username'),
            first_name =self.validated_data.get('first_name'),
            last_name = self.validated_data.get('last_name'),
            email=self.validated_data.get('email'),
            Address=self.validated_data.get('Address'),
@@@
-           PhoneNumber=self.validated_data('PhoneNumber'))
===
+           PhoneNumber=self.validated_data.get('PhoneNumber'))
@@@
        user.save()
```

PS: I strongly recommend to use pythonic `snake_cased` field names instead of `PascalCased` ones, which are usually used for types.

Or try to use single naming convention per class at least.. Because this isn't really appreciated:

```py
            last_name = self.validated_data.get('last_name'),
            PhoneNumber=self.validated_data.get('Address'),
```

You can find more codestyle recommendations in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)